# Extension of the collatz function to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: collatz-conjecture

The **3x+1** map is give as

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{3x+1}{2} & \text{  if x odd} \\ \frac{x}{2} & \text{ else} \end{cases}$$
with domain $\mathbb{N}.$

On this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Iterating_on_real_or_complex_numbers), I found that this function can be extended to a smooth function on $\mathbb{C}$ to

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{4}(1 + 4z - (1 + 2z)\cos(\pi z)).$$

Is this extension unique or is there any reason to consider this particular extension?

Comment: It is not unique. It could be multiplied by any other non-constant analytic function $h$ with the property $h(\Bbb{Z}) = \{ 1\}$ (and such a function exists).